# Difference between documentum workflow and D2 documentum workflow?

Tags: documentum, documentum6.5, documentum7.3, documentum-d2

Can someone please suggest technical differences between normal documentum workflows and D2 based documentum workflows? In terms of different object types and so on?

What is difference between content handling and advanced content handling in D2 documentum?

Kind regards
Tom

Answer (score 0):

Documentum workflow is the base for D2 based Documentum workflow. The key in configuring effective D2 workflows is to create the most basic form of the Documentum workflow. D2 workflows facilitates more configuration capabilities on top of documentum workflows like....condition based intiation, configurable controls for performer selection, task completion based on configured options....

Functionality of the workflow within D2 is dependent on the following variables:

```
  All tasks created in the workflow must be manual.

  In order to add performers to the workflow the add groups must be configured for Documentum Workflow. Any configurations on top of these should be configured in the D2-Config.
```

Some of Advanced Content handling capabilities of D2 are audit; lifecycles and workflows which can all be modified to suit the requirements of the specific type of content or user ; supporting operations on different types of documents using Plugins( c2, o2...) and working with Virtual documents.